# MBP key broken- can I put a replacement key on the Touch Bar?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, touch-bar

On my 2016 MacBook Pro, the 'b' key on the keyboard has quit working. This is quite inconvenient, and unfortunately it will be a while before I can get it fixed.

Is there a way to put a button on the Touch Bar to replace my 'b' key?